# WINAPI CreateThread C not always launch function

Tags: c, winapi

I'm writing a C program.

For thread I use the WINAPI library.

But sometimes the CreateThread function don't launch the function associate.

I used the WaitForSingleObject function with INFINITE param to let my thread start but he never start

The GetLastError functions return always 0,so I don't know where is my mistake

The merge function is call when GTK button is press.

Below you will find my code

```
void merge(GtkWidget *wiget, gpointer data){

    HANDLE thread;
    FtpLogin *login = (FtpLogin *) data;

    thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, mergeThread, login, 0, NULL);

    printf("%ld", GetLastError());

    WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);

    if(thread == NULL)
     puts("error");
}

DWORD WINAPI mergeThread( LPVOID lpParam )
{
   puts("Thread start");

   return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You will need to give more details on the errors or wrong behaviors you get. Have a look at [mcve].

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks for your comment. I don't have any error, the thread just not start. The GetLastError function never return an error code.

Comment: `CreateThread` always launch your function, why you decide that `mergeThread` not executed ?

Comment: puts("Thread start\n");  maybe.

Answer (score 1):

The C run-time library needs some per-thread initialization. `CreateThread()`, which knows nothing about the C RTL, doesn't perform that.

Instead of `CreateThread()`, use `_beginthreadex()`. It's declared in `<process.h>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Same problem. The function is not always call. I think the problem come from GTK while I call the function on the main thread

Comment: @M5623 - you mistake. at first your function is called. at second `puts` fail

Comment: @RbMm Thanks for your answer you mean that puts isn't thread safe ?

Comment: @M5623 no, but `puts` use some c/c++ runtime environment, which will be not initialized in thread created by `CreateThread`. or not use c/c++ runtime in this thread, or use `_beginthreadex` which internally call `CreateThread` + do required runtime initialization. so answer under which we comment is correct

Comment: This answer was true a very long time ago, but not any more

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html), GTK is not thread safe. Anything that interacts with the GUI inside your *mergeThread* function can have unexpected results.

Please refer to the link I provided for more information about multithreaded GTK applications to see how to use GDK instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I already use this functions to interact with GTK object on other thread. The CreateThread function is call on the main thread. For the other thread I only display a text on the console